# One input splitted into two filters

Tags: angular, pipe

currently im trying to filter a location with the postcode or the city.

This is my input:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label> Adresse: </mat-label>
                <input matInput (ngModelChange)="FilterChanged()"  type="text" name="ort"  [(ngModel)]="adressFilter"/>
            </mat-form-field>
```

This is my filter, that works with only one input(here i listed them both)

```html
FilterChanged(){
    this.personsFiltered = of(this.persons).pipe(
      map( p => (!this.adressFilter || this.adressFilter.trim() === '') ? p:p.filter((i: any) => i.ort?.toLowerCase().includes(this.adressFilter.toLowerCase()))), //would work if i delete the other one
      map( p => (!this.adressFilter || this.adressFilter.trim() === '') ? p:p.filter((i: any) => i.plz?.toLowerCase().includes(this.adressFilter.toLowerCase()))), //same like above
      map(p => p.slice(0, 30))
    )
  }
```

My goal is that the user can write postcode or the city in one input. If i use only one adressFilter it works, if im trying to filter both via one filter it does not work.

Comment: your code applies filters one after another, so the person should match both conditions in your case. put boths of the conditions to `p.filter(here)` and filter out only items that do not match both of the conditions

Comment: Yes that was the solution, ty !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it one condition wouldn't work? Something like `i.ort?.toLowerCase().includes(this.adressFilter.toLowerCase() || i.plz?.toLowerCase().includes(this.adressFilter.toLowerCase()`